# Find pattern in a string

Tags: c++

I have created a method called `findPattern` which will read through a string and check if another string exists in the first one.

Ex:

string s1 = "abcdxbc";
string pattern = "bc";

The method will check if "bc" exists in `string s1` and print the start index of each occurrence of the pattern "bc" inside `s1`.

This is how the method is called:

```
string s1 = "abcdxbc";
string pattern = "bc";

findPattern(string s1,string pattern);
```

Currently, my method can find a pattern in 1 string only, but I want it to check 2 strings.

This is how it will be called: `findPattern(string s1, string s2, string pattern);`

Please help

Thanks

**findPattern method code:**

```
void findPattern(string s1, string pattern)
{
   int s1Len = s1.length();
   int pLen = pattern.length();
   
   //for loop to move along the string s1
   for (int i = 0; i <= s1Len - pLen; i++)
   {
       int j = 0;
       while(j < pLen && s1[i + j] == pattern[j]) //check that each char in pattern matches the char in s1
       {
            j++;
       }
       
       //if pattern is found inside s1
       if(j == pLen) cout << i << " ";
   }
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is "variadic arguments"

Comment: And what you are trying to do, is already implemented in the Standard. Search for `std::find` or `std::find_first_of`

Comment: Another thing: Have you considered what the function should return, if it finds the needle in both given haystacks? You simply shouldn't do it like that.

Comment: @Iyashi but ``std::find`` will only get the index of the first occurrence inside a string, for example if a pattern exists twice in my string, it would get the index of the first occurrence only.

Comment: call find again with the new starting iterator

Comment: If you want all indices of needle, you can do something like `lastIndex = std::find(string, lastIndex)` in a loop until nothing is found anymore.

Comment: Why not just call the function a 2nd time for the 2nd string?

Comment: Yes you could make a 2 line function that calls your current findPattern() twice once for each input string.

Comment: Your function does one thing -- that's all it should do. If you need to use it twice, then loop over your array (or `std::vector`) of strings calling your function once for each string. Never customize the number of arguments just to fit one special circumstance -- you end up with a function that isn't re-usable.(unless you happen to have that one special case again)

Comment: @Iyashi woud a for loop work if was to use ``lastIndex = std::find(string,lastIndex)``?

Comment: Of course. See @david-c-rankin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from your comment on [std::basic_string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) only finding the first occurrence -- that ignores the **return** value and the `size_type pos` parameter taken as its second argument. To find all substrings, you simply save the number of characters returned and add that plus the length of the substring together to use as the next position to search from, e.g.

```
void findPattern (const std::string& s, const std::string& sub)
{
    size_t  pos = 0,
            nchars = 0;
    
    while ((nchars = s.find(sub, pos)) != std::string::npos) {      /* find sub */
        std::cout << sub << " at: " << nchars << '\n';              /* output result */
        pos = nchars + sub.length();                                /* update pos */
    }
}
```

Putting that together with a loop that calls the function for each of the strings `"abcdxbc"` and `"abcabcb"`, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void findPattern (const std::string& s, const std::string& sub)
{
    size_t  pos = 0,
            nchars = 0;
    
    while ((nchars = s.find(sub, pos)) != std::string::npos) {      /* find sub */
        std::cout << sub << " at: " << nchars << '\n';              /* output result */
        pos = nchars + sub.length();                                /* update pos */
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    std::string str[] ={ {"abcdxbc"}, {"abcabcb"} },            /* array of strings */
                sub {"bc"};                                     /* substring to find */
    
    for (auto iter = str; iter != str + 2; iter++) {            /* loop over strings */
        std::cout << "\nchecking for: '" << sub << "' in '" << *iter << "'\n\n";
        findPattern (*iter, sub);                               /* locate substrings */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/findallsubs

checking for: 'bc' in 'abcdxbc'

bc at: 1
bc at: 5

checking for: 'bc' in 'abcabcb'

bc at: 1
bc at: 4
```

You can modify the outputs to fit your needs.

All of the `std::string.find`, `.find_first_of`, `.find_first_not_of`, ... work the same way. Let me know if you have further questions.